# Logging Python script code to a file based on flow of execution

Tags: python, logging

I have three different python files `a.py`, `b.py` and `c.py`. These three scripts are interconnected such that functions of `a.py` are imported in `b.py` and functions of `c.py` are imported in `b.py`.

`b.py` is the main file. Running `b.py` will import functions from other two files. I want to write the python code that is being executed to a file such that the code to be saved in the file based on order of execution from `a.py`, `b.py` & `c.py`.

Can you please suggest an efficient way.

A file with flow of code execution from three python scripts

sample content in final file:

```
test() # coming from a.py
test1() # coming from c.py`
def test3():
  print("test2")

test3()
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach would be to apply a [logging decorator](https://ankitbko.github.io/blog/2021/04/logging-in-python/) to all functions. The decorators must be applied to all functions, including those imported, in one file, to set up one single output file and have everything logged in order.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement it without explicit modifications to the contents of the file (like adding decorators, as suggested in another answer), you can make use of [`sys.settrace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.settrace). An implementation of a call-logging trace function could look something like this:

```py
import sys, logging, pathlib


# This will be used to only trace your code and not system stuff
traced_path = pathlib.Path("C:\\Path\\To\\Your\\Sources").resolve()


def log_calls(frame, event, arg):
    # We only want to monitor function call events
    if event != "call":
        # ... but we don't want our trace function to be unregistered,
        # so we return it to ask the interpreter to keep using it
        return log_calls
    
    # We can get all necessary information from the frame object
    # 1. The function name
    func = frame.f_code.co_name
    # 2. The file name
    file = frame.f_code.co_filename
    
    # It's also called for special things like module root scopes,
    # which you probably don't want to log
    if file.startswith("<") or not file:
        return log_calls
    
    # For convenient manipulations
    file = pathlib.Path(file).resolve()
    
    # If you're only interested in the functions from your set of files,
    # you can check the filename against it, either via file.samepath(other),
    # or via a subdirectory
    if not file.is_relative_to(traced_path):
        return log_calls
    
    # You can log it whatever way you can, from print(..., file=...)
    # to having a logger configured to write to a file
    logging.debug(f"{func}()  # coming from {file}")


# Now we tell Python to use this function for tracing.
# It will be invoked automatically in a set of situations,
# listed in the docs I've linked above,
# including "call" for each function call
sys.settrace(log_calls)
```

Note that if you're interested in logging not only the function calls, but all lines of code, your best bet is to use the `"line"` events instead, and to read the lines from the source files via `frame.f_code.co_filename`, `frame.f_code.co_lnotab` and `frame.f_lasti`, but this is a significantly harder task. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3.11/reference/datamodel.html#index-55) for documentation on code and frame objects.

Comment: Can you let me know if the above code prints the entire python code that's being executed. I am confused what to pass for the function arguments like frame, event, arg

Comment: @Avinash The above code logs every function call along with the file it happens in. If you'd rather log every line, it is also possible, but significantly harder due to how you'd have to extract line numbers manually from a binary format. As for the trace function, you don't call it, the interpreter does. I see now that I forgot to register it in my sample code, I'll add it now